# Speeding up positional access to a std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, stdmap

I find myself in a situation where I have to access a std::map by position. Since `std::advance(iter, position)` is slow af, I want to add a second data structure to speedup this operation.

My idea: Maintain a vector for every key-value pair in the map. Then access the vector by position, `vector[position]->second`.

When erasing/inserting a new element I obviously have to remove the iterator from the vector. But besides that the iterator-preserving properties of std::map seem to be sufficient.

Question: Is this a good idea?

Alternative: Maintain a vector of `map::keys`. Then access vector by position an use the key to lookup the value in the map,`map[vector[position]]`. Is this smarter?

Comment: try std::unordered_map, it often speeds up finding the element.

Comment: This is actually a very good point, I will give this a go tomorrow! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If iteration through the `map` is your primary performance issue, then you should be using a `flat_map` (not as of yet part of the standard, but Boost has a decent one). If you don't have one of those, just use a `vector<pair>` that you keep sorted using the same comparison function you would have used in your `map`.

You can use `std::lower_bound` as the equivalent function for being able to find a value by its key. You can also use the iterator returned from `std::lower_bound` as the position for doing a single-element insertion of a new element. Everything else works just like any other `vector`; simply keep it sorted and you'll be fine.

Comment: Great idea. My primary concern with this is that my map/vector grows potentially very large and insertion might take a very long time if the insertion occurs early in the vector and I have to shift the entire thing down.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. The same complexity can be achieved by a sorted `std::vector`

Don't use a map, but a vector. Keep it sorted by key. Binary search by key is logaritgmic. Access by position is the fastest.

The only drawback is that inserting and removing needs memory reallocation.  You may test its performance and consider if it's worth.

Comment: And then I  would use std::algorithms with a lambda to search through it to find the spot to insert into, etc. Ill consider this, thanks. Biggest problem in my case would seem potential copying of the entire vector on memory reallocation.